# git clone project from inside docker container

Tags: git, ssh, virtual-machine, ssh-keys, docker

I am running few containers of docker, in my development machine. My development machine has got the authorized keys. Is there a possible way to do Git project clone from inside docker container, by leveraging the host ssh keys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your keys to docker container by SCP command or by using shared folder functionality (http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/)

Answer (score 7):

If you use  an SSH agent, you can also bind-mount the SSH agent socket within the container, e.g.:

```
docker run -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/auth.sock -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/auth.sock myimage …
```